# Call method in view when a property changes

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I work to an application using MVVM pattern. In view i have a text box and a canvas. In canvas I will draw some lines, as many as the text box indicates. The text of text box is bind to a int property in view model. Also the text box has a command that updates the property in view model. I know how to rise property changed event on view model.
My question is: Is there a way to call the drawing method from view when property changed event is raised?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about putting the canvas/drawing code in a separate user control with the number of lines as a dependency property bound to the ViewModel.  You can then handle the dependency property change event inside the user control and do the drawing.